# ASMX and ASHX Performance Benchmarks

Tags: asmx, ashx

Hi is there a way to measure / monitor the performance of .NET web services (ASMX) and .NET Http Handlers (ASHX)? I would like to see how long it takes to process a SOAP request vs how long it takes to process a HTTP GET request.

Comment: kind of but i would like to see performance benchmarks in our production environment where we can't turn on tracing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up using Firebug and YSlow to see the bytes transfered and total time elapsed.

Comment: Which one was fastest in your case?

Answer (score 1):

You could override and instrument [IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest.aspx) to monitor performance of web pages and, well, HTTP handlers, but web services expose no such method.

You'll probably have to write an [HTTP module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx), so you can have a crack at every request.